# Can you fix my simple Array Method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I made a very simple method that takes in an int array, and duplicates it. So if I made an array with the numbers 1,2,3... the method should return 1,1,2,2,3,3.
However, there seems to be a problem I can't figure out. When I printed z[1], 2 was the output and not 1. Any help would be great.

```
public class random{

public static int[] duplicate(int[] a) {

int[] r = new int[a.length * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    r[i * 2] = a[i];
    r[i * 2 + 1] = a[i];
}
return r;
}




public static void main(String[] args) {

    int []z = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
    duplicate(z);
    System.out.print(z[1]);


}
```

}

Comment: What do you think `return r;` does?

Comment: Your output is from the z array you defined and directly printed . What don't you understand?

Comment: This is hilarious, people are so upset with my question they are downgrading my other questions. Sick dude .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign your array to the variable z on return of the difference function. i.e.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []z = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
    z = duplicate(z);
    System.out.print(z[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for actually answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply passing the array z into your method, and that method returns an r.
Printing z[1] comes from your original array, z, and not from r (the array that your method returns). You'll have to print from r, and not from z. One way you can do this is:

```
 int[] r=duplicate(z);
 System.out.println(r[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reassign your z array after you call the function.

```
     z = duplicate(z);
```